# How do I get JQuery to work with CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

I use CakePHP 2.0

I am following this guide
http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2009/01/19/jquery-in-the-cakephp-world-part-1/

I have included in my add.ctp viewer

```
$this->Javascript->link('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js', false);
```

and I have

```
var $helpers = array(‘Javascript’, ‘Html’, ‘Form’);
```

in my controller...

The error I am getting is

```
Missing Helper
Error: JavascriptHelper could not be found.

Error: Create the class JavascriptHelper below in file: app/View/Helper/JavascriptHelper.php
```

Comment: So the tutorial you've linked to is for 1.3, not 2.0. There's a lot of differences.

Comment: please note, that at the very top of the post i have a link to an updated version of the article, which shows how to use jQuery + CakePHP 2.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, if you're using CakePHP 2.0 then jQuery comes already packaged with the framework.

See [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html) for more detail on how to use jQuery and the JSHelper in CakePHP 2.0

The tutorial you've linked to is for version 1.3, so that's why it doesn't work....